# Update/uninstall with Pip packages installed with apt (and vice versa)

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, apt-get

There are a number of resources that compare and contrast the advantages and disadvantages of using `apt-get` and `pip` to install, update, and uninstall python packages.

What I cannot find is a resource that indicates what happens if something that is installed by one package manager is updated or uninstalled by the other.

When I run `pip list`, it lists a lot of packages that are installed, most of which on my system were installed by `apt-get` and not `pip`.

So, are these two package managers able to manage packages installed by the other? Or, is `pip` able to manage a package installed by `apt-get`, but then `apt-get` is messed up afterwards. Is `apt-get` able to manage a package installed by `pip`?

Comment: rule of thumb: if in doubt, never use more than one package manager. All package managers I know of are selfish - they expect to be the only one merging packages into your system. But with pip you have a lot of options: You can use `pip install --user` to install packages into your user's home directory. An even better choice is to use `virtualenv` to make sure you do not interfere with system's python.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to try and avoid using two (or more) package managers at the same time. It's not very likely that they will cooperate correctly and smoothly.

If possible, pick one of them and use it. Combine them only if you really need to. Usually you don't.

There are ways of avoiding conflicts such as

- `pip install --user <package>` which installs the package into the user's directory only
- [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) which allows you to have packages installed per application/project - this is a very good idea since various projects might need different versions of the same package and it's easy to move such project do a different computer etc.
- [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv) - Python 3 has a built-in support for virtual environments